# Get the child id when persisting an entity with cascade

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using hibernate entity manager (4.2.16).
I'm having trouble when merging an existing entity, after adding a new child to it. I would like to get the id of the newly created child, but the id is not set.
Here is my model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
@GenericGenerator(name = "gen_identifier", strategy = "sequence", parameters = {
    @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "SQ_PARENT")
})
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "gen_identifier")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> children;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
@GenericGenerator(name = "gen_identifier", strategy = "sequence", parameters = {
    @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "SQ_CHILD")
})
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "gen_identifier")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Code to create the parent (transaction 1):

```
public Long saveParent() {
    Parent parent = new Parent();

    entityManager.persist(parent);

    System.out.println("saveParent : parent.id = " + parent.getId());
    return parent.getId();
}
```

Code to add child (transaction 2)

```
public void addChild(Parent parent) {
    Child child = new Child();
    child.setParent(parent);
    parent.getChildren().add(child);

    entityManager.merge(parent);
    System.out.println("addChild : parent.id = " + parent.getId());

    // The following give me a null id
    System.out.println("addChild : child.id = " + parent.getChildren().iterator().next().getId());

    System.out.println("addChild : child.id = " + child.getId());
}
```

When executing the code, I would expect the child id to be not null. Here is the output I get :

```
saveParent : parent.id = 1000
addChild : parent.id = 1000
addChild : child.id = null
addChild : child.id = null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge always returns a newly intiallized entity which you should use as the entity for you operation all the changes that happens after call to merge are only reflected in the entity returned from merge.So in order to solve your problem you need to change you code as below

```
public Parent addChild(Parent parent) {
Child child = new Child();
child.setParent(parent);
parent.getChildren().add(child);

parent=entityManager.merge(parent);
System.out.println("addChild : parent.id = " + parent.getId());

// The following give me a null id
System.out.println("addChild : child.id = " + parent.getChildren().iterator().next().getId());

System.out.println("addChild : child.id = " + child.getId());'
return parent;
```

}

You should also return the parent from this method so that any code calling this method should use the newly generated parent rather then using the old one which does not have any changes done by merge in it.

To read more about the merge() visit the below link

http://blog.xebia.com/jpa-implementation-patterns-saving-detached-entities/